# What is the difference between Shallow Information Architecture and deep Information Architecture?

Tags: user-research, information-architecture, user-centered-design, ux-designer

I am new to User Centric Design process, wish to learn Information architecture in detail. Please help me understand difference between Shallow Information Architecture and deep Information Architecture? Example should help me to understand better.

Thanks-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic definitions:
Shallow = more top level categories, not many sub catgeories. 
Deep = less top level, more sub.

Donna Spencer is a great expert and the practical guide of IA is an easy ready with lots of info based on experience.
http://maadmob.com.au/design/ia

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn about Information Architecture there is a great book on the subject - Information Architecture for the Web and Beyond (4th Edition) by Peter Morville & Jorge Arango.

However, this question has been asked before: [Should we use ‘narrow and deep’ or ‘broad and shallow’ navigation pattern on mobile devices?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30825/should-we-use-narrow-and-deep-or-broad-and-shallow-navigation-pattern-on-mob) and there is a good diagram showing the difference between shallow and deep structures in this question.